# Restore large PostgreSQL dump (gzipped - .sql.gz) with skipping errors (psql/pg_restore)

Tags: postgresql, psql, restore, dump

I'm trying to make a `.sh` script that will restore my database (about a 1.3Gb gzipped) with command below

```
dropdb dbname && createdb -O pguser dbname
gunzip < /path/to/backups/backupname.sql.gz | psql dbname
```

It goes ok, but at some point i got next error and script process stops:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
ERROR:  missing data for column "columnname"
CONTEXT:  COPY spots, line 533475: text_of_line
```

So, is there any way to ignore errors like this and skip it to proceed restoring?

Comment: pg_restore would do that. showing the errors in the end.

Comment: Maybe your zipfile is damaged or truncated. try `gzip --test yourfile.zip` to verify.

Comment: @wildplasser `gzip --test` says nothing, and `pg_restore -d dbname file.sql.gz` says `pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive`. I'm a little confused

Answer (score 2):

try adding `ON_ERROR_STOP=0`:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=0 <<EOF
> select now();
> error;
> select now();
> EOF
              now
-------------------------------
 2018-01-18 12:04:57.713847+00
(1 row)

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "error"
LINE 1: error;
        ^
              now
-------------------------------
 2018-01-18 12:04:57.714335+00
(1 row)
```

or use `pg_restore` if you have backup in non-plain-text formats

Comment: i got backups, made by this command `pg_dumpall -c -U postgres  | gzip -9 > ${BACKUPS_PATH}/${DUMP_FILE}.sql.gz`, `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=0` not working for me, still stops on error...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe update to use zcat instead, pg_restore will not work with that archive type, I have had success with the below.

```
zcat backupname.sql.gz | psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 --username=postgres -W dbname
```